# Confusing increment use

Tags: java, arrays, int, increment

So I was doing a UIL practice test and this problem came up.

```
public void fun(int[] list){
list[2]++;
list[1] = list[0];
list = new int[4];
list[2]++;
}

//////////////////////////
// client code
int[] vals = {2, 7, 3};
fun(vals);
out.print( Arrays.toString(vals) );
```

I tried it out and got [2, 2, 5] but the answer was [2, 2, 4]. Since it was just list[2]++, I figured that it would just add, but it didn't. Why was the last increment not included in the output?

Answer (score 3):

```
list = new int[4];
```

The last line incremented an element in a different array.

Answer (score 0):

`list = new int[4];` this changed the local reference `list` address.
but, vals kept the old address.
so, last increment done to a new array. and vals kept the old array with the operations did to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fun(vals)` the local variable `list` is pointing to the location of `vals`. After a new array is created, however, the local variable `list` now points to an entirely different block of memory (though the reference itself is still in the same location in memory).